# How to transform out-adjacency list to in-adajcency list?

Tags: graph-algorithm, pseudocode, adjacency-list

For directed graphs G = (V,E). That representation maintains an array A[...] indexed by V , in which A[v] is a linked list. The linked list holds the names of all the nodes u to which v points, i.e., nodes u for which (v, u) ∈ E. (Technically, A[v] contains a pointer to the first item in the linked list).This is the default adjacency list format and can be thought of as an `out- adjacency` list representation

An `in-adjacency` list representation would be one in which A[v] is the list of nodes that point to v.

Can anyone help to give me a pseudocode for an `O(|V | + |E|)` algorithm that transforms the out-adjacency list representation into an in-adjacency list repre- sentation. And please explain why your algorithm is correct and why it runs in O(|V | + |E|) time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in **O(V + E)** but for that you have to modify the insert operation in linked list to be done in constant time **O(1)**.

That could be easily done, by keeping a separate pointer `last`, where `last` points to the last element inserted in a linked list. With help of `last`, insert operation in a linked list can be done in **O(1)**,as opposed to usual **O(N)**.

Now coming to the problem, lets say our new `adjacency list` is `adj_new`. We start by traversing our original `adjacency list` starting from the first linked list.

For each element `x` of linked list `A[0]`, we do insert operation:

```
insert 0 in linked list adj_new[x]
```

We do the above for each of the linked lists. Since traversing the entire adjacency list takes time
 **O(V + E)**, and every insert operation takes **O(1)** time, the total time taken is **O(V + E)**

Following is the pseudocode :

```
For each linked list A[i]
{
 for each element x of A[i]
 {
  append i to linked list adj_new[x]
 }
}
```

`adj_new[]` is the in-adjacency list. If you look carefully its nothing but reversing the direction of each edge of your directed graph.

Comment: Sorry, i am still not too clear about you explanation, can you explain it in more detail

Comment: @ttllm What do you dont understand?